# How do I uninstall or disable the entire dash in Unity?

Tags: unity, uninstall, unity-dash

I love using Unity except for the dash. Is it possible to uninstall or disable the dash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the dash inside unity but you can always head to a different desktop environment.

Try gnome-panel to fall back to classic gnome desktop. You can install it by:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`

Then log out and log in to GNOME Desktop.

Comment: Alright. I was afraid of hearing that. But with the launcher, HUD, and global menus, Unity is awesome. But the dash is way too slow (not to mention alt+tab!) so perhaps the best answer is to just install Synapse and ignore the dash :)

Comment: As far as I am aware about the slow responsiveness of the dash you can set the dash blur to Static or No blur. Download (CCSM) `Compiz config setting manager` from Software center and go to Unity Plugin option, then in `Experimental Tab > Dash Blur > Static OR No Blur`. This should increase the responsiveness of the dash at cost of look. But if you are feeling kinda paranoid then just install `gnome-panel, synapse, AWD and global menu applet for gnome` and leave the unity way on its own ;) You'll miss the HUD though.

Comment: Thanks for the details there! Changing the blur does seem to help a bit.